# How to build up modifications and apply them at once using lenses in Scala?

Tags: scala, lenses, quicklens

I have designed a case class that looks superficially like this:

```
case class Moo(foos: Seq[Foo], bar: Bar) {
  require(foos.length == bar.baz.length)
  ...
}
```

This type will be consumed by a Java program, so I have created a convenient `MooBuilder` to make it easier to populate the fields without having to explicitly instantiate `Foo`s, `Bar`s, and other types contained by these.

Currently `MooBuilder` creates copies of objects when a field is set by its methods. I had read about lenses and wanted to give them a try to make the implementation cleaner.

So I installed [quicklens](https://github.com/adamw/quicklens) and rewrote the builder, but came across this situation:

```
def addFooAndBaz(foo: Foo, baz: Baz): MooBuilder = {
  moo = moo
    .modify(_.foos)   .using(_ :+ foo)  /* (1) */
    .modify(_.bar.baz).using(_ :+ baz)  /* (2) */
  this
}
```

Immediately after (1), `moo.foos` has one more element than `moo.bar.baz`, and this makes the `require` call fail, so it never gets to (2) to fix the mismatch.

I know I can work around the issue by doing all the copying by hand (as I was doing before) or by removing the `require` call in my case class's constructor. Still, I'd like to know: **is there a standard way to solve the problem of doing several updates that make sense combined but not on their own, using lenses in Scala?**

Comment: What if instead of using lenses, you just add a method to your `Moo` case class called `withFooAndBaz` that performs the copying? Then you can just write `moo = moo.withFooAndBaz(foo, baz)`. Using a lens is just abstracting calls to `copy` - you never actually mutate an instance of `Moo`, but instead return a new updated copy at each step.

Comment: @Eric: that's what I was doing, and it involves a lot of explicit copying (I have more nested classes than this example). I would like to know if lenses can help in an elegant way.